# Not able to display a Jasper report on the browser , Allocate exception for servlet JaspersJob_servlet java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jasper-reports

Help me out i have an issue with the jasper report over a servlet, error is mentioned below

> SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet JaspersJob_servlet
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1149)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Servlet code:

```
 package jasper_job_Print;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.sql.*;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignQuery;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;

 public class JaspersJob_servlet extends HttpServlet {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = -3478873702336546526L;

 protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {
Connection con=null;
File reportFile = null;
JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
ResultSet rs=null;
Statement statement = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cloudinterdataset",                                                      "root","cosmos123");
        reportFile = new File("C:\\abd\\JasperJava\\report10.jasper");
        String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM userdetails "
                + "ORDER BY Lastname ";
        statement = con.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(sql1);
        if (!reportFile.exists())
            throw new JRRuntimeException(
                    "File WebappReport.jasper not found. The report design must be compiled first.");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception : "+e);
    }

    try {
        JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new
                JRResultSetDataSource(rs);
        System.out.println("Filling Jasper PDF report...");
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader
                .loadObject(reportFile.getPath());
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null,resultSetDataSource);
        System.out.println("Done!");
        if (jasperPrint != null)
        {
            JRExporter exporter = null;
            exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,
                    jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,
                    response.getOutputStream());

            exporter.exportReport();
        } else {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>JasperReports </title>");
        out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../stylesheet.css\"    title=\"Style\">");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body bgcolor=\"white\">");
        out.println("<span class=\"bold\">Empty response.</span>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception :"+e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Yes my report for java applet works, i have been debugging my code and stuck at this point, examples show similar codes work and my web.xml  has servlet name and class mentioned properly and i have called the servelt through a jsp action and get

Comment: Hey all i got the solution for the above problem any one has same issue just reply down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a very simple solution i did not put the Jar Files in my project lib. Its working now, just got time to post my answer